# Scrape html siblings as individual items?

Tags: python, html, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

Simple question that I just can't seem to resolve. I'm working on scraping [this website](https://app.reviewr.com/gsb/site/gsb2015/FdxbQVIpg8920,bx5052,bx5051,cb24476?sort=Popular&group=1305626&keyword=) using and I would like to collect the name and votecount of each entry listed on this and subsequent pages.

So far, I've created a spider in Scrapy that does just that, however the results aren't formatted correctly. Instead of an individual item for each company that lists name and votecount, I'm getting names for all companies and votecounts of all companies on any give page.

i.e.  I want this:

```
Item    voteCount   startUpName 
1       17,950      1stCompany 
2       11,487      2ndCompany 
3       7175        3rd company
```

but I'm getting this:

```
Item    voteCount               startUpName
1       17,950,114,877,175      1stCompany, 2ndCompany, 3rdCompany
```

From what I can tell, it's how I'm defining my xpaths, but no matter what I try I can't get it to work. I'm sure I could probably fix this in post production, but I'd really like to know scrapy is working beneath the hood.

Looking at my code below, does anyone have suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from GSB.items import *


class startupSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "startupSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["reviewr.com"]

    #In the future this can be handed to the spider
    start_urls = [
        'https://app.reviewr.com/gsb/site/gsb2015/FdxbQVIpg8920,bx5052,bx5051,cb24476?sort=Popular&group=1305626&keyword='
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="page-more"]')), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        items = []

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="submission-list"]'):
            item = GSBItem()
            item['startUpName'] = sel.xpath('//a/div/text()').extract()
            item['voteCount']   = sel.xpath('//div[@class="vote-count"]/text()').extract()
            item['desc']        = sel.xpath('//div[@class="teaser"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're XPaths inside the loop are not based on the main query context.

**Try:**

```
for i, sel in enumerate(response.xpath('//div[@class="submission-list"]/div[contains(@class,"submission")]/div[@class="content"]'), start=1):
    startup_name = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/div[@class="name"]/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
    votes = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="count vote-widget "]/div[@class="vote-count"]/text()').extract()[0]
    print "[{}] {} has {} votes".format(i, startup_name, votes)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] ProteCão has 17950 votes
[2] megaBoost has 11487 votes
[3] HoushmandSafar has 7175 votes
[4] SyncrHome has 6759 votes
[5] kidIN has 4398 votes
[6] KooKapp has 3979 votes
[7] Alerta UV has 3814 votes
[8] Athlon Hunters has 3775 votes
[9] Fernweh has 2738 votes
[10] Getmyweather has 2692 votes
[11] Feaglett has 2474 votes
[12] Legend of the coins has 2434 votes
[13] ACERCATE has 2306 votes
[14] Smart Automation has 2003 votes
[15] Nas4Nas has 1379 votes
[16] Hier_my_spa! has 1298 votes
[17] Watch Agent has 1130 votes
[18] LiftSync has 1053 votes
[19] WooU has 1005 votes
[20] Giftr has 909 votes
[21] FLNT has 659 votes
[22] Tencil has 616 votes
[23] Taker has 596 votes
[24] HidroBrain has 522 votes
```

See this presentation for more information:

http://www.slideshare.net/scrapinghub/xpath-for-web-scraping

Comment: This did the trick! My xpaths we're off because I didn't know how to deal with the 'submissions' vs. 'submissions first' in the HTML. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @rrphenix I'm glad my answer helped! It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you select the wrong path in the for loop. So you are only checking the parent list, so text() will return every child items text. I've also changed the name xpath for the company. Notice the contains function in the first xpath, it's to include the first element that has more than one class. The correct Xpath should be something like this:

```
 for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="submission-list"]/div[contains(@class, "submission")]'):
        item = GSBItem()
        item['startUpName'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="name"]/text()').extract()
        item['voteCount']   = sel.xpath('//div[@class="vote-count"]/text()').extract()
        item['desc']        = sel.xpath('//div[@class="teaser"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```